# how can i catch errors if variables are not set?

Tags: python

How can catch the error caused by a module variable not being set when the function is called

so example i have this code

```
file = "whatever the file path is"
menu= [] #this is a global variable

def ordermenu():
    with open(file) as f:  # read file
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
        next(reader, None) #skip the header

def showmenu():
    for i in range(len(menu)):
        print(menu)

ordermenu()
showmenu()
```

In this function i need to catch the error.

NOTE: i won't be using those global variable as parameters.

Comment: Could you use try: except:?

Comment: What error are you looking for? It seems like `ordermenu` didn't add anything to `menu` so `showmenu` has nothing to do. You could just check `if len(menu) == 0` in that function.

Comment: im just looking for errors where i could say 'Variables not set' if the variables aren't set

Comment: "variable not set" is vague. You don't have any undefined variables in your example.

Comment: Hi, could you explain what "variable not set" means?

Comment: In the example, `menu` is set to an empty list. There are no unset variables.

Comment: if i could assume that there's no variable that is not set when the function is called then an error should pop up

Comment: "In this function I need to catch the error" - you've posted two function, which one? And what is the error? I added `import csv` fixed your file name and ran your code. No error.

Comment: i neeed to create an try except error in the showmenu function

Answer (score 2):

It is called `NameError` for something not defined. Just wrap your code with `try`-`except` like this:

```
try:
    b = a+1
except NameError:
    print("a not defined")
```

Comment: That program didn't have a name error. OP said "variables not set" which I think is too vague to answer at this point.

Comment: I think the NameError hits at the module csv is not loaded.

Comment: I took that to just being that OP didn't post a complete example. Maybe that's what the problem is though.